# Abstract class, which is subclass of something else

Tags: python, inheritance, abstract-class

According to some recepies in `Python` to define `Abstract` `class` we should declare that it's abcmeta like this:

```
class BaseStrategy(metaclass=ABCMeta):
```

But what if this class is already subclassed from other class?

```
class BaseStrategy(bt.Strategy):
```

Use other options (`interfaces`, `exception` in base class) instead?

Note that I tried:

```
class BaseStrategy(bt.Strategy, metaclass=ABCMeta):
```

With such traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Projects/trading-bot/main/lab/backtrader/netflix.py", line 13, in <module>
    from main.lab.strategy import RSISimple, RSIBuySell, SMACross, SMA_RSI, HolyGrail, MACD_ADX, BBands
  File "D:\Projects\trading-bot\main\lab\strategy\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .rsi_simple import *
  File "D:\Projects\trading-bot\main\lab\strategy\rsi_simple.py", line 3, in <module>
    from main.lab.strategy.base_strategy import BaseStrategy
  File "D:\Projects\trading-bot\main\lab\strategy\base_strategy.py", line 6, in <module>
    class BaseStrategy(bt.Strategy, metaclass=ABCMeta):
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

Possible that bt.Strategy uses abstract classes too.

Comment: Asked on `Backtrader` (library used) forum too: https://community.backtrader.com/topic/114/strategy-inheritance/6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message tells you that your base class already has a metaclass that is not a superclass of your metaclass. Python requires that `issubclass(B, A)` implies that `issubclass(type(B), type(A))`.

You got

```
class AMeta(type): pass
class A(metaclass=AMeta): pass
class BMeta(type): pass
class B(A, metaclass=BMeta): pass
```

which is invalid because `BMeta` (`type(B)`) is not a subclass of `AMeta` (`type(A)`). You can fix it by declaring the derived metaclass:

```
class BMeta(AMeta): pass
# or even
class BMeta(type(A)): pass

class B(A, metaclass=BMeta): pass
```

In your concrete case it'd look like this:

```
class BaseStrategyMeta(ABCMeta, type(bt.Strategy)): pass
class BaseStrategy(bt.Strategy, metaclass=BaseStrategyMeta): pass
```

Comment: Edited to address the actual problem.